# Is σωτήρ or Σωτήρ proper when refering to Christ?

Tags: greek

From the different Greek Bibles and online references I've looked at, different versions of same verse may or may not capitalize the Σ.

Does σωτήρ properly refer to Christ and does it matter if its capitalized?

What is the difference between σωτήρας and σωτήρ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earliest Greek manuscripts were written in all majusculars/ uncials.

You can see an example by viewing the [Codex Sinaiticus](http://www.codexsinaiticus.com/en/) which is a relatively early Greek manuscript of the Bible, both Old and New Testaments.

So, the distinction between σωτήρ and Σωτήρ did not exist. Rather, what you would have wrote and/ or read was ΣΩΤΗΡ.

As for σωτήρας and σωτήρ, the former is a word in modern Greek, while the latter is a word in Koine Greek. Both are equivalent to the English word "savior."

Comment: Thank you! So would it still be proper to just have σωτήρ in Koine Greek?

Comment: @MikeFisher: I see nothing wrong with it.